# Getting QWidget's Windows messages without subclassing it and reimplementing QWidget::winEvent

Tags: c++, windows, qt, windows-messages

Is it possible to intercept `QWidget`'s Win messages without reimplementing QWidget::winEvent? Is there something like `installEventFilter` but for Windows native messages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can install a native message event filter function at the application level with `QAbstractEventDispatcher::instance()->setEventFilter()` (see the [documentation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qabstracteventdispatcher.html#setEventFilter)).